# Is it possible to get "all images" from ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

Assume that someone has a task to make sure that all pictures in applications (they are using main library for custom ImageView) are "in the same style". Let it mean that all pictures have to have single border color, and, if not, custom ImageView should take care about repainting. Is it possible to achieve via getting information about "all images" from extended ImageView?

More general question: is it possible to get "the resulting image on the screen" before actual start, analysing information in custom components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unclear about what you are trying to ask here, but it seems like you can simply extend the default `ImageView` class to take care of custom border. Then everywhere within your app, use your custom class instead of the Android framework's `ImageView`.

Comment: Can ImageView "know" when new image (and it's parameters) is added? I mean, some hooks/observers/etc.

Comment: Each one of your custom `ImageView` holds its own image, so there is no sense of "all images" in the app. As long as each `ImageView` does its work correctly and customize the image properly, then that will apply to every image.